# JavaFX TableColumn setPreferredWidth on a Resizable Column

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a table with three columns and I want to make sure the total width of the columns is equal to the width of the table, so I'm using CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY.

I want the columns to start with a width I specify, but can be modified by the user.

If I do this:

```
albumTable.setColumnResizePolicy ( TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY );
artistColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(albumTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.4));
yearColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(albumTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.2));
albumColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(albumTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.4));
artistColumn.setResizable(false);
yearColumn.setResizable(false);
albumColumn.setResizable(false);
```

The columns are sized as i want:

[image: good]

But if I change `setResizable()` to `true`, then the columns all become the same size:

[image: bad]

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Simplifying the setting of preferred width to something like `column.setPreferredWidth ( 200 )` doesn't make any difference. The width is always divided evenly between all columns.

**Is there any way to set the preferred width (or actual width) of columns while still allowing those columns to be resized by the user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` starts with the ratio of column's  maximum width. To start at a ratio of 4:2:4,

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
column1.setResizable(true);
column2.setResizable(true);
column3.setResizable(true);
column1.setMaxWidth(40000);
column2.setMaxWidth(20000);
column3.setMaxWidth(40000);
```

This method may solve the problem just when radio is required.

Comment: This should be good enough for my needs. I'll test it out and let you know if it works!  Thanks.